# How can I add two named vectors together to create a Nx2 matrix from a Nx3 in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to set up a two class problem from a 3 class matrix. I need to set it up as "Interesting vs Others" where "Others" is the sum of "Not interesting" and "OK" column vectors.
I am starting with Table 1 and I'm unsure how to get to Table 2.

```
Table 1:
   Interesting Not interesting        OK
2    0.3043478       0.1739130 0.5217391
6    0.2857143       0.2380952 0.4761905
7    0.0000000       0.5555556 0.4444444
9    0.1818182       0.2727273 0.5454545
10   0.4000000       0.1333333 0.4666667
11   0.2558140       0.2790698 0.4651163

Table 2:
   Interesting Others        
2    0.3043478 0.6956522
6    0.2857143 0.7142857
7    0.0000000 1.0000000
9    0.1818182 0.8181818
10   0.4000000 0.6000000
11   0.2558140 0.7441860
```

I am working with decision trees and here is some of the code prior to Table 1:

```
pred=predict(my_tree,newdata=validation)
head(pred)
pred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ideas (assuming you are working with data frames, not matrices)

```
# subtract interesting from 1
table2 = data.frame(Interesting = table1$Interesting, Others = 1 - table1$Interesting)

# add up everything but the first column
table2 = cbind(table1[1], Others = rowSums(table1[-1]))

# if it is really just two columns, use +
table2 = table1[1]
table2$Others = with(table1, `Not interesting` + OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need to do is:

```
t1$Others <- t1$'Not Interesting' + t1$OK
```

Then just delete the unused columns:

```
t1$'Not Interesting' <- NULL

t1$OK <- NULL
```